# Copy message parts from message to message in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

The only way I could find is to write a custom .NET assembly to perform the task.
Is there a way to do it within expression in orchestration? I have an input message that has parts and I'd like to copy those to the destination (mapped) message.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically depends what those parts are, but assuming we're talking about parts that aren't explicitly presented in a multi-part message type, and/or you don't want to use a map for each one, then yeah, the only way is through a helper component.

Comment: Thank you Tomas,
I googled and figured that that would be the only way. Too bad. That means that every time my multipart untyped message goes through dynamic transformation, I have to remember to copy the attachments with an external .NET helper class. I wish there would be something build in in Orchestration syntax to copy parts... also, weird thing I encountered, is that body part Name was "part" and not "Body". Really strange.

Comment: There's really nothing strange about the latter; the name of the body part is meaningless really, the important part is that it has been marked as the body part when it was added to the message :)

Comment: My understanding from the read was that the body part has to be named as "body". As well as it's not enough to mark it IsBody=true, it also has to be added as the first part in the sequence of part (multi-part message case). That's why I was surprised to see that body part message got a different name.

Comment: Sean: I've never personally run into a case where that's required at all, though I can certainly imagine some components or bugs creeping up that might expect that. Still, it's not generally an issue.